# Simple Tooltips on Menu Scrolls with the page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, tooltip

I'm using Simple Tooltips plugin to add tooltips on my menu icons. https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-tooltips/

I have a vertical menu and my problem is when I scroll the page the tooltip scrolls up and down as well. I checked the plugin settings and theres no option to make it fixed in position. How can I fix that issue with CSS? As much as possible I would like the tooltip to appear to the left side of each icon menu fixed in position.

You can check our site here http://scaleup.onebonsai.com

Thanks ad I hoe you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a position fixed to the Zebra tooltip class.
Try this.

```
.Zebra_Tooltip {
    position: fixed!important;
}
```

Cheers and happy coding!

Comment: thanks for the help but tried this and didnt worked.

Comment: Any information in the inspector on what is being applied. A screen or fiddle would be great. Is the change live on your website?

Comment: I just changed it to fixed position so you can check. See http://scaleup.onebonsai.com

Try to scroll down and hover to see tooltip how it behaves. Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be working for me. Did you clear your browser cache. Here is a screenshot of it. http://imgur.com/eFnIrWK

Comment: yes I cleared my cache and I'm seeing the same in your screenshot but the position of tooltips are inconsistent when you scroll down the page. Try to check on mozilla you can clearly see issue. thanks!

Comment: The screenshot I took was in Firefox. Initially you stated that the tool tip scrolled up and down when you scroll. That has been fixed by adding a position fixed. All you need to do now is figure out what styles are overwriting the position of the fixed position at different screen positions. Or as a last measure you could use an alternative tool tip plugin. Cheers